# facing issue while formating the JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON which i am trying to convert as i want through `.map` functions
But i am getting wrong result

As i have a `Array` and inside that i have several `Objects` but after formatting the data i am getting `Array` inside which `Array` then `Object`

**My current json**

```
var cpy = [
      {
            "billdate": "2018-08-01",
            "outlet": "S0001",
            "amount": 10,
            "cash": 5,
            "creditcard": 0,
            "coupon": 0,
            "paytm": 0,
            "credit": 0,
            "swiggy": 5,
            "kb": 0,
            "bigbasket": 0
          },
          {
            "billdate": "2018-08-01",
            "outlet": "S0002",
            "amount": 10,
            "cash": 5,
            "creditcard": 0,
            "coupon": 0,
            "paytm": 0,
            "credit": 0,
            "swiggy": 5,
            "kb": 0,
            "bigbasket": 0
          },
          {
            "billdate": "2018-08-01",
            "outlet": "S0009",
            "amount": 11,
            "cash": 6,
            "creditcard": 0,
            "coupon": 0,
            "paytm": 0,
            "credit": 0,
            "swiggy": 5,
            "kb": 0,
            "bigbasket": 0
          },
          {
            "billdate": "2018-08-02",
            "outlet": "S0001",
            "amount": 10,
            "cash": 0,
            "creditcard": 0,
            "coupon": 0,
            "paytm": 0,
            "credit": 0,
            "swiggy": 55,
            "kb": 0,
            "bigbasket": 0
          },
          {
            "billdate": "2018-08-02",
            "outlet": "S0002",
            "amount": 15,
            "cash": 55034,
            "creditcard": 0,
            "coupon": 0,
            "paytm": 0,
            "credit": 0,
            "swiggy": 5,
            "kb": 0,
            "bigbasket": 0
          },
          {
            "billdate": "2018-08-02",
            "outlet": "S0009",
            "amount": 10,
            "cash": 72213,
            "creditcard": 0,
            "coupon": 0,
            "paytm": 0,
            "credit": 0,
            "swiggy": 10,
            "kb": 0,
            "bigbasket": 0
          }
        ]
```

from the above i am trying to get like below

```
[
    {
        "billdate": "",
        "sales type": "Full total",        //this one is the header
        "S001": "20",  //full total of amount of outlet `S001` date wise i.e for 2018-08-01 and 2018-08-02
        "S002": "30",   //full total of amount of outlet `S002` date wise i.e for 2018-08-01 and 2018-08-02
        "S009": "33"     //full total of amount of outlet `S003` date wise i.e for 2018-08-01 and 2018-08-02
    },
    {
        "billdate": "2018-08-01",
        "sales type": "Totals",
        "S001": "10",
        "S002": "10",
        "S009": "11"
    },
    {
        "billdate": "",
        "sales type": " CASH",
        "S001": "5",
        "S002": "5",
        "S009": "6"
    },
    {
        "billdate": "",
        "sales type": " CREDIT CARD",
        "S001": "0",
        "S002": "0",
        "S009": "0"
    },
    {
        "billdate": "",
        "sales type": "coupon",
        "S001": "0",
        "S002": "0",
        "S009": "0"
    },
    {
        "billdate": "",
        "sales type": "paytm",
        "S001": "0",
        "S002": "0",
        "S009": "0"
    },
    {
        "billdate": "",
        "sales type": "swiggy",
        "S001": "5",
        "S002": "5",
        "S009": "5"
    },
    {
        "billdate": "2018-08-02",
        "sales type": "Totals",
        "S001": "10",
        "S002": "20",
        "S009": "20"
    },
    {
        "billdate": "",
        "sales type": " CASH",
        "S001": "5",
        "S002": "15",
        "S009": "10"
    },
    {
        "billdate": "",
        "sales type": " CREDIT CARD",
        "S001": "0",
        "S002": "0",
        "S009": "0"
    },
    {
        "billdate": "",
        "sales type": "coupon",
        "S001": "0",
        "S002": "0",
        "S009": "0"
    },
    {
        "billdate": "",
        "sales type": "paytm",
        "S001": "0",
        "S002": "0",
        "S009": "0"
    },
    {
        "billdate": "",
        "sales type": "swiggy",
        "S001": "5",
        "S002": "5",
        "S009": "10"
    }

]
```

but when i am running my code firstly for some loops i am getting data as it is there then something like i want

**Here is what i have done**

```js
var cpy = [{
    "billdate": "2018-08-01",
    "outlet": "S0001",
    "amount": 10,
    "cash": 5,
    "creditcard": 0,
    "coupon": 0,
    "paytm": 0,
    "credit": 0,
    "swiggy": 5,
    "kb": 0,
    "bigbasket": 0
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-01",
    "outlet": "S0002",
    "amount": 10,
    "cash": 5,
    "creditcard": 0,
    "coupon": 0,
    "paytm": 0,
    "credit": 0,
    "swiggy": 5,
    "kb": 0,
    "bigbasket": 0
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-01",
    "outlet": "S0009",
    "amount": 11,
    "cash": 6,
    "creditcard": 0,
    "coupon": 0,
    "paytm": 0,
    "credit": 0,
    "swiggy": 5,
    "kb": 0,
    "bigbasket": 0
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-02",
    "outlet": "S0001",
    "amount": 10,
    "cash": 0,
    "creditcard": 0,
    "coupon": 0,
    "paytm": 0,
    "credit": 0,
    "swiggy": 55,
    "kb": 0,
    "bigbasket": 0
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-02",
    "outlet": "S0002",
    "amount": 15,
    "cash": 55034,
    "creditcard": 0,
    "coupon": 0,
    "paytm": 0,
    "credit": 0,
    "swiggy": 5,
    "kb": 0,
    "bigbasket": 0
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-02",
    "outlet": "S0009",
    "amount": 10,
    "cash": 72213,
    "creditcard": 0,
    "coupon": 0,
    "paytm": 0,
    "credit": 0,
    "swiggy": 10,
    "kb": 0,
    "bigbasket": 0
  }
]



function getDataList(jsn) {
  var billdate = [];
  var outlet = [];
  var salesType = [];

  billdate = [...new Set(jsn.map(ele => ele.billdate))];
  outlet = [...new Set(jsn.map(ele => ele.outlet))];
  for (let i in jsn[0]) {
    if (i !== 'billdate' && i !== 'outlet') {
      salesType.push(i)
    }
  }

  return {
    billdate,
    outlet,
    salesType
  }

}


function structureJSON(obj) {
  var arr = [];
  obj.billdate.forEach((ele1, index1) => {

    obj.salesType.forEach((ele, index) => {
      let row;
      if (index === 0) {
        row = {
          billdate: ele1,
          selesType: ele
        };
      } else {
        row = {
          billdate: "",
          selesType: ele
        };
      }
      obj.outlet.forEach((ele2, index2) => {
        var selected = cpy.filter((ele3, index3) => {
          return ele3.billdate === ele1 && ele3.outlet === ele2
        });
       
        row[ele2] = selected[0][ele]
      })
      arr.push(row)
    })

  })

  return arr;

}

console.log(structureJSON(getDataList(cpy)));
```

just want to add the header which can calculate the full total like in the json i wanted

all the data i am getting is perfect just want to add

```
{
        "billdate": "",
        "sales type": "Full total",        //this one is the header
        "S001": "20",  //full total of amount of outlet `S001` date wise i.e for 2018-08-01 and 2018-08-02
        "S002": "30",   //full total of amount of outlet `S002` date wise i.e for 2018-08-01 and 2018-08-02
        "S009": "33"     //full total of amount of outlet `S003` date wise i.e for 2018-08-01 and 2018-08-02
    },
```

**Edit**

as i am using different json of same type but values are different it is showing error as `typeerrorselected[0] is undefined`

```js
var cpy = [{
    "billdate": "2018-09-01",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "amount": 476426,
    "cash": 465818,
    "creditcard": 0,
    "coupon": 0,
    "paytm": 0,
    "credit": 0,
    "swiggy": 10608,
    "kb": 0,
    "bigbasket": 0,
    "zomato": 0
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-01",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "amount": 92141,
    "cash": 87903,
    "creditcard": 0,
    "coupon": 0,
    "paytm": 0,
    "credit": 0,
    "swiggy": 4238,
    "kb": 0,
    "bigbasket": 0,
    "zomato": 0
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-01",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "amount": 115313,
    "cash": 115313,
    "creditcard": 0,
    "coupon": 0,
    "paytm": 0,
    "credit": 0,
    "swiggy": 0,
    "kb": 0,
    "bigbasket": 0,
    "zomato": 0
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "amount": 511153,
    "cash": 490289,
    "creditcard": 0,
    "coupon": 0,
    "paytm": 0,
    "credit": 0,
    "swiggy": 20864,
    "kb": 0,
    "bigbasket": 0,
    "zomato": 0
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "amount": 115704,
    "cash": 112854,
    "creditcard": 0,
    "coupon": 0,
    "paytm": 0,
    "credit": 0,
    "swiggy": 2850,
    "kb": 0,
    "bigbasket": 0,
    "zomato": 0
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "amount": 83597,
    "cash": 83597,
    "creditcard": 0,
    "coupon": 0,
    "paytm": 0,
    "credit": 0,
    "swiggy": 0,
    "kb": 0,
    "bigbasket": 0,
    "zomato": 0
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-03",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "amount": 167421,
    "cash": 167421,
    "creditcard": 0,
    "coupon": 0,
    "paytm": 0,
    "credit": 0,
    "swiggy": 0,
    "kb": 0,
    "bigbasket": 0,
    "zomato": 0
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-03",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "amount": 53775,
    "cash": 53775,
    "creditcard": 0,
    "coupon": 0,
    "paytm": 0,
    "credit": 0,
    "swiggy": 0,
    "kb": 0,
    "bigbasket": 0,
    "zomato": 0
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-04",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "amount": 269711,
    "cash": 264363,
    "creditcard": 0,
    "coupon": 0,
    "paytm": 0,
    "credit": 0,
    "swiggy": 5348,
    "kb": 0,
    "bigbasket": 0,
    "zomato": 0
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-04",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "amount": 58849,
    "cash": 56865,
    "creditcard": 0,
    "coupon": 0,
    "paytm": 0,
    "credit": 0,
    "swiggy": 1984,
    "kb": 0,
    "bigbasket": 0,
    "zomato": 0
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-04",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "amount": 82998,
    "cash": 82998,
    "creditcard": 0,
    "coupon": 0,
    "paytm": 0,
    "credit": 0,
    "swiggy": 0,
    "kb": 0,
    "bigbasket": 0,
    "zomato": 0
  }
]



function getDataList(jsn) {
  var billdate = [];
  var outlet = [];
  var SalesType = [];

  billdate = [...new Set(jsn.map(ele => ele.billdate))];
  outlet = [...new Set(jsn.map(ele => ele.outlet))];
  for (let i in jsn[0]) {
    if (i !== 'billdate' && i !== 'outlet') {
      SalesType.push(i)
    }
  }

  return {
    billdate,
    outlet,
    SalesType
  }

}


function structureJSON(obj) {

  var arr = [];
  obj.billdate.forEach((ele1, index1) => {

    obj.SalesType.forEach((ele, index) => {
      let row;
      if (index === 0) {
        row = {
          billdate: ele1,
          SalesType: ele
        };
      } else {
        row = {
          billdate: "",
          SalesType: ele
        };
      }
      obj.outlet.forEach((ele2, index2) => {
        var selected = cpy.filter((ele3, index3) => {
          return ele3.billdate === ele1 && ele3.outlet === ele2
        });

        row[ele2] = selected[0][ele] //here it is showing error
        console.log(row[ele2])
      })
      arr.push(row)
    })

  })

  return arr;

}


var tableValue = structureJSON(getDataList(cpy))
```

please check my edited part

Answer (score 1):

Would break this down into different functions, getOutletTotals would look something like this:

```js
var cpy = [{
    "billdate": "2018-08-01",
    "outlet": "S0001",
    "amount": 10,
    "cash": 5,
    "creditcard": 0,
    "coupon": 0,
    "paytm": 0,
    "credit": 0,
    "swiggy": 5,
    "kb": 0,
    "bigbasket": 0
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-01",
    "outlet": "S0002",
    "amount": 10,
    "cash": 5,
    "creditcard": 0,
    "coupon": 0,
    "paytm": 0,
    "credit": 0,
    "swiggy": 5,
    "kb": 0,
    "bigbasket": 0
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-01",
    "outlet": "S0009",
    "amount": 11,
    "cash": 6,
    "creditcard": 0,
    "coupon": 0,
    "paytm": 0,
    "credit": 0,
    "swiggy": 5,
    "kb": 0,
    "bigbasket": 0
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-02",
    "outlet": "S0001",
    "amount": 10,
    "cash": 0,
    "creditcard": 0,
    "coupon": 0,
    "paytm": 0,
    "credit": 0,
    "swiggy": 55,
    "kb": 0,
    "bigbasket": 0
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-02",
    "outlet": "S0002",
    "amount": 15,
    "cash": 55034,
    "creditcard": 0,
    "coupon": 0,
    "paytm": 0,
    "credit": 0,
    "swiggy": 5,
    "kb": 0,
    "bigbasket": 0
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-02",
    "outlet": "S0009",
    "amount": 10,
    "cash": 72213,
    "creditcard": 0,
    "coupon": 0,
    "paytm": 0,
    "credit": 0,
    "swiggy": 10,
    "kb": 0,
    "bigbasket": 0
  }
]

function getOutletTotals(data) {
  const totals = {};
  
  data.forEach(item => {
    if (totals.hasOwnProperty(item.outlet)) {
      // Add to existing outlet total
      totals[item.outlet] += item.amount;
    } else {
      // First time we've seen this outlet
      totals[item.outlet] = item.amount;
    }
  });
  
  totals['billdate'] = "";
  totals['sales type'] = "Full total";
  
  return totals;
}

console.log(getOutletTotals(cpy));
```

Comment: i want to add this in my code as i am trying to get `Array` inside that all objects which will have all data, and also the order of data is not correct i want like ` {
    "billdate": "",
     "sales type": "Full total",
    "S0001": 20,
    "S0002": 25,
    "S0009": 21,
    
    
  }` and  `S001` :total of amount for date 2018-08-01 and 2018-08-02 if  03 will be there then it would give all total..full total is giving full total of amount datewise

Comment: @dheerajkumar Order of object literal key names is not guaranteed, would need to use an array. "All objects which will have all data" can you expand on that requirement, what is meant by that?